# Advanced Custom Fields else if

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to display store hours for 3 different locations with Advanced Custom Fields in WordPress. When I take out the entire middle section with the else if statement, it works correctly for the other 2 locations. As soon as I add in the section with the else if statement, the store hours go blank for all pages. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is what I have so far:

First section

```
<?php if (is_single( 3823 ) ){ ?>


<section class="hours">
  <h3>Outlet Hours:</h3>

    <section class="hours-section">
      <?php if(get_field('store_hours')): ?>
        <?php while(has_sub_field('store_hours')): ?>
          <p class="days"><b><?php the_sub_field('store_hours_day'); ?>:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></p>
          <?php if (get_sub_field( 'store_hours_closed')  == "open") { ?>
            <p class="hours-hours">
              <?php the_sub_field('store_hours_morning_time'); ?>&nbsp;am
              -
              <?php the_sub_field('store_hours_evening_time'); ?>&nbsp;pm
            </p>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php if (get_sub_field( 'store_hours_closed')  == "closed") { ?>
            <b>Closed</b>
          <?php } ?>
          <br/>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </section>

</section><!-- .sidebar -->
```

Second Section

```
<?php else if (is_single( 2284) ){ ?>


<section class="hours">
  <h3>Builder Hours:</h3>

    <section class="hours-section">
      <?php if(get_field('store_hours')): ?>
        <?php while(has_sub_field('store_hours')): ?>
          <p class="days"><b><?php the_sub_field('store_hours_day'); ?>:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></p>
          <?php if (get_sub_field( 'store_hours_closed')  == "open") { ?>
            <p class="hours-hours">
              <?php the_sub_field('store_hours_morning_time'); ?>&nbsp;am
              -
              <?php the_sub_field('store_hours_evening_time'); ?>&nbsp;pm
            </p>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php if (get_sub_field( 'store_hours_closed')  == "closed") { ?>
            <b>Closed</b>
          <?php } ?>
          <br/>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </section>

</section><!-- .sidebar -->
```

Third Section

```
  <?php } 
  else { ?>

<?php $other_page = 47; ?> 

<section class="hours">
  <h3>Retail Hours:</h3>

    <section class="hours-section">
      <?php if(get_field('store_hours', $other_page)): ?>
        <?php while(has_sub_field('store_hours', $other_page)): ?>
          <p class="days"><b><?php the_sub_field('store_hours_day', $other_page); ?>:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></p>
          <?php if (get_sub_field( 'store_hours_closed', $other_page)  == "open") { ?>
            <p class="hours-hours">
              <?php the_sub_field('store_hours_morning_time', $other_page); ?>&nbsp;am
              -
              <?php the_sub_field('store_hours_evening_time', $other_page); ?>&nbsp;pm
            </p>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php if (get_sub_field( 'store_hours_closed', $other_page)  == "closed") { ?>
            Closed
          <?php } ?>
          <br/>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </section>

</section><!-- .sidebar -->
```

Comment: Is your "Store Hours" ACF field a "Repeater" field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you forgot a curly bracket or two in your code. I went ahead and changed your if/else statements to use the alternative syntax, which you used in some places in the code block, but not consistently throughout.

```
<?php if (is_single( 3823 ) ) : ?>

    <section class="hours">
        <h3>Outlet Hours:</h3>
        <section class="hours-section">
           <?php if(get_field('store_hours')): ?>
              <?php while(has_sub_field('store_hours')): ?>
                 <p class="days"><b><?php the_sub_field('store_hours_day'); ?>:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></p>
                 <?php if (get_sub_field( 'store_hours_closed')  == "open") : ?>
                    <p class="hours-hours">
                        <?php the_sub_field('store_hours_morning_time'); ?>&nbsp;am
                        -
                        <?php the_sub_field('store_hours_evening_time'); ?>&nbsp;pm
                     </p>
                 <?php endif; ?>
                 <?php if (get_sub_field( 'store_hours_closed')  == "closed") : ?>
                      <b>Closed</b>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                  <br/>
              <?php endwhile; ?>
              <?php endif; ?>
        </section>
    </section><!-- .sidebar -->

<?php elseif (is_single( 2284) ) : ?>

   <section class="hours">
      <h3>Builder Hours:</h3>
          <section class="hours-section">
              <?php if(get_field('store_hours')): ?>
                 <?php while(has_sub_field('store_hours')): ?>
                     <p class="days"><b><?php the_sub_field('store_hours_day'); ?>:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></p>
                     <?php if (get_sub_field( 'store_hours_closed')  == "open") : ?>
                     <p class="hours-hours">
                     <?php the_sub_field('store_hours_morning_time'); ?>&nbsp;am
                     -
                     <?php the_sub_field('store_hours_evening_time'); ?>&nbsp;pm
                     </p>
                 <?php endif; ?>
                 <?php if (get_sub_field( 'store_hours_closed')  == "closed") : ?>
                     <b>Closed</b>
                 <?php endif; ?>
                 <br/>
                 <?php endwhile; ?>
             <?php endif; ?>
         </section>
     </section><!-- .sidebar -->

<?php else : ?>

    <?php $other_page = 47; ?> 
        <section class="hours">
            <h3>Retail Hours:</h3>
                <section class="hours-section">
                    <?php if(get_field('store_hours', $other_page)): ?>
                        <?php while(has_sub_field('store_hours', $other_page)): ?>
                            <p class="days"><b><?php the_sub_field('store_hours_day', $other_page); ?>:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></p>
                            <?php if (get_sub_field( 'store_hours_closed', $other_page)  == "open") : ?>
                            <p class="hours-hours">
                            <?php the_sub_field('store_hours_morning_time', $other_page); ?>&nbsp;am
                            -
                            <?php the_sub_field('store_hours_evening_time', $other_page); ?>&nbsp;pm
                            </p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if (get_sub_field( 'store_hours_closed', $other_page)  == "closed") : ?>
                            Closed
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <br/>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </section>
        </section><!-- .sidebar -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something really simple. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @TristanDespain happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
You should mention type like option, page ,theme
```

Example:

```
$other_page ='2';//pageid
<?php if(get_field('store_hours', $other_page)): ?>
```